# Once Excel sheets in a workbook saved as .csv, cant get back to .xlsm

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. I press a (ribbon) button and a subroutine saves multiple sheets as .csv, shells out to some java code, then comes back. The problem is: once it comes back, the workbook has been converted to a .csv file (the last one saved) and no further .xlsm operations are possible.

How do I fix this?

Amendment:

Has nothing to do with Java or shell. WHENEVER I do this:

```
Sheets("someSheet").SaveAs Filename:=someName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

this changes the ENTIRE workbook to someSheet.csv. Then, the behavior of the workbook gets weird. I haven't been able to save as .csv without changing EVERYthing.

Comment: if we could see the subroutine code, it would help us provide a better solution.

Comment: To boil it down, has nothing to do with Java. sinply:

Comment: Need to see more of your VBA.

Comment: You can try `Workbooks.Open` with the parameters `False` at the end. This should open up again your previous xlsx file. Example:  `Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\test.xlsx", False`

Answer (score 3):

Use `SaveCopyAs`.

It leaves your original workbook as is and saves a copy.  Requires 2007 or newer but since you mention a ribbon button that should be fine.  From the link:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\TEMP\XXXX.XLS"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178003(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, the `Save As` operation, creates a new copy of the workbook with the new name and format/style, then closes the old one.

A .csv file doesn't support macros, so your workbook is behaving as designed.

In order to get back to your original workbook after doing the `Save As`, you will need to re-open the original workbook and then close the new .csv workbook.

Otherwise, you could come up with a custom `Export` method to just export the data on each sheet to a .csv file, but that seems needlessly complex.

Comment: OK. I'm answering my own question. A few minutes after I posted this question I figured out the answer and it's really simple and really useful. Here is a function that saves a sheet named "x" as "x.csv".